# Toggling .sliced off text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to toggle the text that is hidden after the `.slice` slices off the first 100 characters.

I have the following code:

**.html**

```
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <p class="pdp-product-description">This has more than 100 characters and it is showing that it is sliced after the 100th</p>
    <a href="#"><span class="view-details">View Details</span></a>
  </div>
```

**.js**

```
$(function() {
    var hiddenDescription = $('p.pdp-product-description');

    hiddenDescription.each(function(){
        var t = $(this).text();
        if(t.length < 100) return;
        $(this).html(
            t.slice(0,100)+'<span>... </span>'+
            '<span class="hidden">'+ t.slice(100,t.length)+'</span>'
        );
    });

    $('.view-details').click(function() {
      $('.pdp-product-description').toggleClass('.hidden');
    });
});
```

The current setup doesn't seem to be working, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The class is on the spans, not the paragraph, but you're toggling it on the paragraph.
2. You don't include the `.`  when calling `toggleClass`. The dot is for introducing a class selector in CSS, it's not part of the name of the class.

So:

```
$('.pdp-product-description span').toggleClass('hidden');
// ------------------------^^^^^----------------^
```

**Live Example:**

```js
$(function() {
  var hiddenDescription = $('p.pdp-product-description');

  hiddenDescription.each(function() {
    var t = $(this).text();
    if (t.length < 100) return;
    $(this).html(
      t.slice(0, 100) + '<span>... </span>' +
      '<span class="hidden">' + t.slice(100, t.length) + '</span>'
    );
  });

  $('.view-details').click(function() {
    $('.pdp-product-description span').toggleClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <p class="pdp-product-description">This has more than 100 characters and it is showing that it is sliced after the 100th - This has more than 100 characters and it is showing that it is sliced after the 100th</p>
  <a href="#"><span class="view-details">View Details</span></a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```